# How to deploy NodeJs application in Production Server without source code

Tags: node.js

We are developing a nodejs application, we have tried to deploy nodejs application without source code by using PKG plugin(https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg) and nexe. Both are creating EXE file by bundling the source code. Now how to read configuration file(which is stored database connection etc) in production, because configuration file will be part of exe. And we will not able to modify the file.

Do we have any other tool to handle production deployment without source code and having separate application configuration file.

Comment: Did you actually read [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg#config)? Unless it's loaded via a non-string-literal `require()`, you don't have to do anything special when using `pkg` to compile the binary.

Comment: Thanks we are able to read the config file using non-string-literal .